# Angular 6 : How to have two way communication between components created dynamically using componentref

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

How to have two-way communication between components created dynamically using component-ref. I have multiple instances of the same component in my parent component.

> I'm not happy with deleting all the components and create those again.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please have a look at [How to create Minimal, Compete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. You should although explain what you've tried so far and what exactly is your project you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

```
const CompDynamicFactory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(yourComponent);
const yourComponent = this.container.createComponent(CompDynamicFactory );
this.nameComp = yourComponent.instance;
```

add an `@input` and `@output` to you're dynamic component

and then via the instance you can communicate between the components dynamically.

Example:

```
this.childComp.instance.nameEvent.emit();
```

Comment: How will change detection happen if I have multiple instances of same component ? How can I detect change in children when instance data changes in parent??